# skip title import csv file

Tags: php, csv

with my this code it is also import title of excel i want to skip title while i am inserting records in database. This is my csv upload file i want to skip title of columns in import how it's 
    possible i know that it's possible..

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'footer.php'; 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
  $db= 'ashutosh'; // Database Name.
  mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
  $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
  {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
    $sql = "INSERT into contact(user_id,contact_1,contact_2,contact_3,email,tin_no,cst_no) values ('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
    fclose($file);
     echo "<script>";
     echo "swal('Sucess!', 'File Imported Sucessfully!','success')";
     echo "</script>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "sweetAlert('oops','Select Csv File','error')";
    echo "</script>";
  }
}
?>
<div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
  <?php include 'admin_leftside.php'; ?>
<aside class="right-side">                
<section class="content-header">
  <h1>Upload Csv</h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li class="active">Upload Csv</li>
  </ol>
</section>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
  <section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <form method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
                <p class="help-block">Only CSV File Import.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="Import" >Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first column is the one containing the title (mostly it is) then why do not you use a boolean value to indicate it. Eg:-

```
$isTitleSkipped = false;
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
      if(!$isTitleSkipped)
      {
        $isTitleSkipped = true;
        continue;
      }

$sql = "INSERT into contact(user_id,contact_1,contact_2,contact_3,email,tin_no,cst_no) values ('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]')";
mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

**Warning:-** Stop using **mysql_***. **It is deprecated**.

Comment: it is goes in infinite loop @Let me see

Answer (score 0):

i got my result in this way

```
$k= 1;
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
  if($k!=1)
  {
    $sql = "INSERT into contact(user_id,contact_1,contact_2,contact_3,email,tin_no,cst_no) values ('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]')";
    mysql_query($sql);
  }
  $k++;
}
```